# Arquillian in-container test: only first test passes, others fail

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, junit, integration-testing, jboss-arquillian

I wrote some container tests to see if the correct exceptions are thrown. If I run each test in the test class separately they work, but if I run all tests inside the class at once, only the first test passes and all others fail. The error is: `java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: de.paylax.exception.user.KYCValidationAlreadyAskedException`.

I run the tests from eclipse (JUnit4 Runner).

This is my test Class:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class PaymentBoundaryExceptionTests extends InContainerTest {

    @Inject
    private PaymentBoundary paymentBoundary;

    @Inject
    private ContractControl contractControl;

    @Inject
    private UserControl userControl;
/***********************************************************************
     * Exception Tests
     */

    /**
     * Check if Exception is thrown when wrong payout amount
     */
    @Test(expected = WrongTransactionAmountException.class)
    @UsingDataSet({ "datasets/common/common.yml", "datasets/payments/payments.yml" })
    public void PaymentBoundary_WrongPayOutAmount_WrongTransactionAmountException() {
        ContractEntity contractEntity = contractControl.findContractByContractCode("goodsContract");
        paymentBoundary.createPayout(100, 20, 10, contractEntity.getPayee(), contractEntity, "test");
    }

    /**
     * Check if Exception is thrown when wrong transfer amount
     */
    @Test(expected = WrongTransactionAmountException.class)
    @UsingDataSet({ "datasets/common/common.yml", "datasets/payments/payments.yml" })
    public void PaymentBoundary_WrongTransferAmount_WrongTransactionAmountException() {
        ContractEntity contractEntity = contractControl.findContractByContractCode("goodsContract");
        paymentBoundary.transferFromWalletToWallet(contractEntity.getPayer(), contractEntity.getPayee(), 100, 20, 10,
                contractEntity);
    }
    // .... more tests here
```

I am guessing that there is something wrong with my test setup.
Here is my InContainer-Test:

```
public abstract class InContainerTest {

    /**
     * Create the Web Archive.
     * 
     * @return the web archive
     */
    @Deployment(testable = true)
    public static final WebArchive createDeployment() {
        // loads the pom configuration
        File[] dependencies = Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml").importRuntimeDependencies().resolve()
                .withTransitivity().asFile();
        // loads the mockito framework for testing
        File mockito = Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml").resolve("org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19")
                .withTransitivity().asSingleFile();
        // adds the package for MyProject pointing to the RestMyProject api
        WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class).addPackages(true, "de.MyProject").addClass(RestMyProject.class)
                .addAsLibraries(dependencies).addAsLibraries(mockito)
                // adds the test perisistence xml configuration
                .addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
                // adds the test beans.xml and the log4j2.xml
                .addAsResource("test-beans.xml", "META-INF/beans.xml").addAsResource("log4j2.xml", "log4j2.xml")
                // adds the MyProjectMapping.xml
                .addAsResource("MyProjectMapping.xml", "MyProjectMapping.xml")
                // EMail Templates
                .addAsResource("HTMLEmailTemplate/admin-info.html", "HTMLEmailTemplate/admin-info.html")
                // SQL
                .addAsResource("datasets/scripts/truncate-users.sql", "datasets/scripts/truncate-users.sql")
                .addAsResource("datasets/scripts/autoincrement-users.sql", "datasets/scripts/autoincrement-users.sql")
                .addAsResource("datasets/scripts/contracts.sql", "datasets/scripts/contracts.sql");
        ;
        return war;
    }
}
```

Also, is it wrong that I am using `@UsingDataSet()` on each test rather than once on the class? For my understanding, this way the tables get reset and seeded for each `@Test`.

Comment: Doing a quick overview I don't see anything wrong, have you tried to debug your test (you can use embedded container to make it easier) and check why the exception is thrown? Also try to move the using dataset on class level to see if it is something related to APE or not.

Comment: hey thanks, I already tried moving the dataset to the class level, but it did not help. I tried debugging the test, but unfortunately it does not stop on my breakpoints. do you know by any chance the settings to debug an in-container test?

Comment: Probably you are using managed or remote mode which means that the process is running in another JVM. So you can either start with remote debugging or use embedded mode dependencies so it is used in same JVM as IDE so you can debug as normally you would do.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, took me some time to get remote debugging working. It was related to an error in my yaml-dataseed files. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding @UsingDataSet you can set at class level. APE takes care of removing data after each test. You can modify this behaviour but IIRC works in this way